# iOS opengl game. unexpected touch behaviour causes store rejection

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, appstore-approval

We need some advice here.
We developed an ios game using opengl. the app uses an EAGLView which receives the touch events and implements a custom renderer.

we have tested the binary both in the simulator and device, from ios version 3 to 4.2.1. Everything is just OK.

so, we submit for approval and after review receive rejection arguing that the game does not provide functionality, and that it only has a main menu with three buttons all of which take the user to a webpage...

In fact there are three buttons in the game menu, but only the first one is a link to "more" about the game online... the others when pressed take the player to the other sections of the game.
We have been unable to reproduce this, my guess right now is that the new ios version (5) changed something in the API and the touchbegan and touchend methods are acting differently.. so i'm downloading the latest version to try that.

In the resolution center, the responses we got are really not useful, they didn't said anything about the system versions used during review, we asked for more details, but only got the same cold answer.

Any suggestions in how to approach this problem i'll really appreciate it.

I'm also thinking that maybe we should remove all the links from the menu. the response from the review was just: 'we do not provide pre-approval for any apps. you have three buttons leading to a webpage'

Thanks for the help!.

Comment: Test the App with ios5 and see what happens... 4.2.1 is really old.

Comment: Agreed; at least test it in the iOS 5 simulator that comes with Xcode 4.2. But if you update a device then you can't subsequently restore it to an earlier version of the OS so you may want to apply some caution there.

Comment: Weird. Is it possible you are dynamically setting the target/action of your buttons, and that code is going awry in some way? Perhaps you end up with all of the buttons pointing to the same webpage.

Comment: Hmm, does it have to do with the Retina display? I think for Cocoa, that doesn't require any programming changes. The screen resolution is 640x960 pixels, but the system scales it so it's 320x480 points and you interact with it the same way. The same might not be true for OpenGL. As a result maybe the touch location is always coming up on the first button. I'm just shooting from the hip here.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing's changed with `touchesBegan:` etc as far as I'm aware, but a smart way forward might be to check whether `UITapGestureRecognizer` is available (it is as of iOS 3.2), and if so attach one of those to your `EAGLView` and use its `locationInView:` (inherited from `UIGestureRecognizer`) when an event fires.

Apart from updating you to the current recommended API and buying you some insurance against some OS-specific issue in `touchesBegan:`, it'll automatically give you exactly the normal built-in behaviour for how long a touch needs to be and when a tap is recognised without any effort on your part.

That said, is it possible that inadvertently relying on some other undocumented effect of the current API (such as the order in which calls to `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` will occur, for example) is causing you to get incorrect bounds for your buttons?

Comment: Thanks. i've never used UITapGestureRecognizer, will check that. meanwhile, it looks that there is a problem with locationInview for the handler of the touch, i use 'self' as a reference for the EAGLView active. can´t say anything more until i have latest sdk running... will update what happens.

Comment: I just tested the game in ios 5 simulator. i couldn't reproduce the behaviour suggested by the apple review. all the buttons work just fine. I think we don't have other option but remove the links and remove the button that lead to the page if that the reason for rejection.

Comment: If all three buttons are doing the same thing at Apple's end, won't that just cause the two remaining buttons both to do the same thing?

Comment: i removed any calls to the browser from the menu, now is literally impossible to launch a URL from the app, so the only thing the remaining functions do is take the player to the rest of the game. the deleted button is actually the one that was supposed to open the page (as originally intended). i think it's the safest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are only testing your code in the simulator, so your bug could be related to something physical that only happens on the device.

Do you have portrait and landscape mode ? maybe the os is changing your coordinates around when using a real device, this could account for the bug, say a button that's supposed to be horizontal suddenly turns vertical and occupies all the buttons touch zone ?

Just a thought.

Comment: This could very well be the issue.  I had this exact same thing happen with my own reusable OpenGL UI implementation and spent a great deal of time messing with 90 degree transforms under the various portrait vs. landscape setups.